# jquery-editable-select issue with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm using the plugin [jquery editable select](https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select) to display an editable select.

Although it works on firefox and chrome navigator, it doesn't show the option list on IE when clicking on the scroll bar ?

```
$('#select').editableSelect({filter: false}).on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
    $('#lastselected').val(li.val());

});
```

How can I fix this on IE? And can I use this plugin to search different options using input text separated by comma or space?

Comment: Looks like this issues has been raised: https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/issues/46 Are you seeing any console errors in IE?  What version of IE are you targeting?

Comment: Has anything ever worked in IE?

Comment: @jmargolisvt  I'm using IE8 and there isn't any error on the console. The issue mentioned is not the same thing as my problem. Actually, The click on an option works but the scroll using the mouse click (to jump to the bottom of the list for example) made this problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion/opinion... it's probably not worth your time to get IE8 working.  If it works in IE10 and Edge, you're good.

Comment: even with IE Edge and 10 it doesn't work.

Comment: Can u add a fiddle with relevant code